# RRSet with DNS name foo. is not permitted in zone bar

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am using the [route53](https://github.com/heavywater/chef-route53) cookbook in Opscode Chef to add a newly created VPC node to Route 53.

When I try to create a record named `foo` for the hosted zone `bar.website.net`, I get the error `RRSet with DNS name foo. is not permitted in zone bar`.

I am pretty sure that this is an AWS configuration issue, not an issue with the cookbook, but I could easily be wrong about that. What's the fix for an issue like this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the format I needed to use when entering arguments.

To add the record `foo.bar.website.net`, I was setting the `name` field to `foo`. I actually needed to set it to `foo.bar.website.net` - I was caught off guard because in the AWS Route 53 console one simply needs to type the leading material.

Comment: Documentation is a little confusing: "The name of the domain. This must be a fully-specified domain, ending with a period as the last label indication. If you omit the final period, Amazon Route 53 assumes the domain is relative to the root."

Comment: @DiegoF.Durán "Amazon Route 53 assumes the domain is relative to the root" that refers to the root domain, indicated by "." at the end of FQDN. Eg: if you provide "host.example.com" instead of "host.example.com." AWS will add that extra "." at the end. Hope that clears the confusion.